# Calendar millis difference giving error when dates belongs different years

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, android-calendar

I am trying to calculate millisecond difference between two dates for countdown timer.It is ok when 2 dates belongs to the same year but when one of the dates belongs to another year, it gives me negative milliseconds value so `countdowntimer` jump into the `onFinish()`.

How can i solve this?

```
// tarih = 01/01/2020 and zaman = 00:00, now date is in 2019
public long getCalendarTimeInMillis(String tarih,String zaman){
    String[] tarihParts = tarih.split("\\/");
    String[] zamanParts = zaman.split("\\:");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(tarihParts[1])-1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(tarihParts[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(zamanParts[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(zamanParts[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


    long left = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis() ;
    System.out.println(left/1000/60/60/24);
    return left;
 // sout result : -354
 }
```

Comment: You never set the year on `calendar`, so it's not a date in 2020, it's in the past, hence the negative time difference.

Comment: OMG, its emberrassing :)) thanks for that

Comment: We all do this.  Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes... =)

Comment: Sometimes — I’d say always, indeed — you just need not to use the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class. Use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), and there will be no forgetting the year, or your compiler will tell you. Add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use on API levels strictly under 26. Also calculating the difference will get easier, more readable and less error-prone.